# color icons upto the hover position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have 10 circles (Fontawesome icons) horizontally placed. I want to fill colors to them when the user hover on any icon. For ex: if the user hovers on the 5th circle, all the circles upto the 5th circle should fill in color. (Something like in a rating system) How can i do it?

Following is the code which i render 10 circles.

```
export const RatePersonalityCard = ({}) => {
for (let score = 1; score < 11; score++) {
    let scoreList = [];

        scoreList.push(

            <div className="trait_vote_single tooltip" style={{fontSize:'40px',color:'gray'}} onClick={() => handleClick(score)}>
                {/*<div className="trait_vote_circle"></div>*/}
                <i className="fa fa-circle-thin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a className="trait_value" style={{marginTop:'-34px',marginLeft:'-1px'}}>{score}</a>
                <span className="tooltiptext2 unchange_div" style={{marginLeft: '-40px'}}>{starvalue}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className="">
            <div className="single_trait_rate width_100 text_align_center">{userTraits.trait_name}</div>
            <div className="trait_vote_div">
                {scoreList}
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: look into for loops

Comment: You can try something like this.. https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

Comment: Why use javascript at all for hovers?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hover event for each for every score list item that adds a class to the currently hovered item and everything prior. Then add a blur event to every item to remove the class.

```
function handleHover(e) {
  let index = scoreList.indexOf(e.target);

  for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
    scoreList[index].classList.add('highlight');  
  }
}

function handleBlur(e) {
  scoreList.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('highlight');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No CSS example.  I don't see great value in adding any JS to something that can simply done via CSS.  If you also need a click event, it's as simple as 1 class on 1 span.  I'd also recommend reading:

[Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScrip](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/) which my code does not do.

```css
span .fa-star{
  display: none;
}

span:hover > .fa-star{
  color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

span:hover > .fa-star-o{
  display: none;
}

span { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
```